# Python - Is there a way to convert a string to bytes16?

Tags: python, byte, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I need to convert a string to bytes16 in python.

Currently I'm using this function:

```
auxData = data.encode()
auxData = binascii.hexlify(auxData)
```

but that just returns a byte object,

i have also tried:

```
        auxData = data.encode()
        auxData = binascii.hexlify(auxData)  
        while(len(auxData)<32):
            auxData = auxData + aux
```

that loop is supposed to ensure that the object has all 32 digits as a bytes16 should have.

All of this is to send a bytes16 to a Smart Contract in my private ethereum blockchain. We have a contract Factory but I can't call the needed function because the objects types doesn't match.

Changing the data types to just bytes will double the gas consumption.

Any ideas?